# Parsing the json and storing it in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parsing

i'm very new to this web related problems, please help

i'm working on sencha which proves to be very difficult wen it comes to json parsing . . . .

so i'm planning on retrieving the data to the html page and then load it into my js file. . .

so here is the problem:

i've already asked about it and got a reply..

http://jsbin.com/uwuca5

but now wen i use the html source code locally in my system or even by using the IIS i couldn't parse the data. . . . . . .

here is the link for my json file:

http://compliantbox.com/optionsedge/sample.php

i'm trying to use this link in my code and retrive the data but the data is returning null

Please Help

Thank you,

Comment: Can you show *your* actual code for retrieving the data? (Just the ajax call, but unedited if you would because if you edit it, you might remove the vital piece of information.)

Comment: and what's with the one liners :/

Comment: "html source code locally in my system or even by using the IIS" which is your coding platform?

Comment: Also you should change the output content type, currnetly its `Content-Type:text/html` and it should be `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Are you trying to retrieve the data from a different "origin"? For instance, when running locally on IIS (ajax stuff mostly doesn't work unless you're using a server), are you trying to reach out to `http://compliantbox.com/optionsedge/sample.php` to get the data? If so, that won't work in most cases (see the link for why). For instance, if I modify the JSBin code I gave you in my previous answer to use `http://compliantbox.com/optionsedge/sample.php` instead of `http://jsbin.com/uwura4`, it fails ([example](http://jsbin.com/uwuca5/4)).

Cross-origin calls are possible, but you largely have to be in charge of both sides of the call for them to work. There's [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (requiring special headers from the server, and support in the browser that's missing in IE6 and IE7; it's in IE8 but you have to use an `XDomainRequest` instead of an `XMLHttpRequest`), and there's [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) (requiring the source to support JSON-P explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sencha, but it seems that you're trying to make a cross-domain AJAX call (calling the url http://compliantbox.com/optionsedge/sample.php from within another domain, e.g. from within your local web-site) which is basically not allowed (at least by using XmlHTTPRequest object).

I'd suggest you to take a look at these posts:

1. [Forum post on jQuery web-site](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie)
2. [The jQuery cross-domain AJAX guide](http://www.usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide)

-- Pavel

Answer (score 0):

If you need read the JSON from a different domain you can try first read the document from your server and serve it.

Jquery:
   `$.getJson("Url-in-your-domain");`

Url-in-your-domain:
   Read the remote document and serve it.

Try if you don't find any solution.